# hibernate generic dao overloading removeById

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, orm, dao

Im implementing hibernate ORM in my java project.
Ive downloaded source from [github](https://codeload.github.com/tromberg/hibernate-generic-dao/zip/master)
Ive compiled hibernate-maven-web included in samples.
Now lets assume i want to overload method in one of the implementations
For example CitizenDAOImpl.java
Before my changes it looked like that.

```
package sample.googlecode.genericdao.oldworld.dao;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import sample.googlecode.genericdao.oldworld.model.Citizen;

/**
 * <p>
 * This is the implementation of the Citizen DAO. You can see that we don't
 * actually have to implement anything, it is all inherited from GenericDAOImpl
 * through BaseDAO. We just specify the entity type (Citizen) and its identifier
 * type (Long).
 * 
 * <p>
 * The @Repository allows Spring to recognize this as a managed component (so we
 * don't need to specify it in XML) and also tells spring to do DAO exception
 * translation to the Spring exception hierarchy.
 * 
 * @author dwolverton
 * 
 */
@Repository
public class CitizenDAOImpl extends BaseDAO<Citizen, Long> implements CitizenDAO {


}
```

All i did was override **removeById** that would just call super class.
Later on im planing to add some ecrypt functionality so id will all be scrambled.

```
package sample.googlecode.genericdao.oldworld.dao;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import sample.googlecode.genericdao.oldworld.model.Citizen;

/**
 * <p>
 * This is the implementation of the Citizen DAO. You can see that we don't
 * actually have to implement anything, it is all inherited from GenericDAOImpl
 * through BaseDAO. We just specify the entity type (Citizen) and its identifier
 * type (Long).
 * 
 * <p>
 * The @Repository allows Spring to recognize this as a managed component (so we
 * don't need to specify it in XML) and also tells spring to do DAO exception
 * translation to the Spring exception hierarchy.
 * 
 * @author dwolverton
 * 
 */
@Repository
public class CitizenDAOImpl extends BaseDAO<Citizen, Long> implements CitizenDAO {

    @Override
    public boolean removeById(java.io.Serializable id) {
        return super.removeById(id);
    }
}
```

when i run **mvn clean install** it gives me error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
1:compile (default-compile) on project hibernate-maven-web: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Dev/spike/hibernate-maven-web/src/main/java/sample/googlecode/generi
cdao/oldworld/dao/CitizenDAOImpl.java:[26,24] name clash: removeById(java.io.Ser
ializable) in sample.googlecode.genericdao.oldworld.dao.CitizenDAOImpl and remov
eById(ID) in com.googlecode.genericdao.dao.hibernate.GenericDAO have the same er
asure, yet neither overrides the other
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

I understand that its ambiguous call and both BaseDAO and CitizenDAO  do inherit GenericADO at some point.
What is good solution in this case?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually your method doesn't override the superclass method, you should use 
`Long id` instead of `Serializable id` as a parameter to make it overridden.

The superclass is a **bounded generic** class, since it has `ID extends Serializable` restriction on ID's generic type. Note, generic information is not stored in the runtime and would be erased. It's just a compile time information. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html for details.

Here your custom method doesn't override superclass method, moreover, both method's are generic and have the same erasure. So in runtime, after erasure, these methods would have the same signature and JVM would be confused which one to call. That's why compiler fails with error.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I'm kind of from C++ world so i would assume some kind of virtual inheritance to manually choose method in run time.What do we do in Java in such case?

Comment: Why do you need `Serializable` type on ID here? According to class definition, it must be `Long`. If you need another type of ID, consider creating new class that `extends BaseDAO<Citizen, Serializable>`. If you need a method which accepts `Serializable` ID in the current class, you can choose another method name (and don't forget to remove `@Override` annotation in such case). But in such a way I have doubts on necessity of the method, because it's quite fragile. You will have to cast types manually and will catch `ClassCastException` in runtime if you pass something different from `Long`.

Comment: Ive changed it to Long , the problem remains.

Comment: Exactly the same error? Can't believe it, that's strange.. Can you attach updated code and the error message?